# Why is my jQuery fadein failing with IE 10?

Tags: jquery, fadein

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work in IE?

http://jsfiddle.net/GASxF/1/

```
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
  $('#tempoffline').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: At least it's not working for me in IE 10.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What happens?  What *should* happen?

Comment: works fine with me IE 10 - 9 and 8

Comment: do you have js disable?

Comment: IE10 on your desktop or IE on your tablet?

Comment: Works find with jQuery 1.9.1, but not 2.x. Seems like a jQuery bug to me. In your fiddle where you use `'40000'`, only text such as `'slow'` or `'fast'` should be in quotes. A number of milliseconds should not have quotes.

Comment: Why does your fiddle use `'40000'`?

Comment: Are you using Windows 7 or 8?  If 8, are you using desktop IE or metro?

Comment: yeah, remove apostrophes from the `'40000'` string

Comment: It never fades in for me on IE 10 -- just stays hidden. Did the jsfiddle link above work for you in IE?

Comment: Try this jsfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/GASxF/9/

Comment: If I change it to jquery 1.9.1 it works in IE 10, if I leave it at 2.x it does not. So - I think Mooseman figured the bug out.

Comment: there is a display none property in css. please remove it and then try

Comment: Seth, from jQuery 2.x was removed support for old explorers. Use newest jQuery 1.x instead just like all people do.

Comment: @Stano i didn't think we can include IE10 in 'old explorers', but apparently yes, we can!

Comment: @roasted I don't understand, that fading with jQuery 2.x doesn't work in IE9, but works good in IE10. Dunnno what else doesn't work.

Comment: @Stano for me doesn't work in IE10 with jquery 2.0.2 but works with edge version 2.x

Comment: @roasted Oh now I understand. I used to test fiddles on a separated page: http://jsfiddle.net/GASxF/1/show/ and there it normally fades. But you'right, in the iframe @ http://jsfiddle.net/GASxF/1/ it doesn't work in IE. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can read about issues with fadeIn in IE here - http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/ .

But won`t scroll do the work for you?

Another possible workaround that I saw is like that:

$("#divToHide").hide().fadeIn(6000);

Comment: Your article is from 2008 so it has zero to do with IE10.

Comment: Interestingly, when testing with IE11, IE11 Enterprise, Compat., and IE8 emulation modes all worked. But normal IE11, with no modes set, did not work at all. The element is a `div`, fyi. It's supposed to fade in gracefully, on page load. `$("#mydiv").hide().fadeIn( 1500 )` displayed but no fadein, no animation. However, `$("#mydiv").hide().fadeTo( 1500, 1 )` displayed and animated. The effect wasn't as graceful as in Chrome or even IE 11 Enterprise Mode, but it did fadein. Also, the delay is shorter than in Enterprise Mode, despite the same delay time set. But it did work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want that:

```
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
  $('#tempoffline').delay(40000).fadeIn();
});
```

Or that:

```
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
  $('#tempoffline').fadeIn(40000);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I was using 'slow' -- but I think Mooseman figured it out.

Comment: @Seth ok tested in IE10 and doesn't work for me too. Seems like a bug in jquery 2.0.2, check your console

Answer (score 0):

It appears Mooseman had it right -- but with jQuery 2.x. Thanks.